# how to install javax and apache plugins in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache, plugins

I'm new to java and trying to rebuild in eclipse 3.4.2 an old package that require javax (classes InternetAddress, Session and others) and org.apache.xpath.* (I don't know exactly why). I'm looking for update sites but google reports billions of pages. An explaination about how/where to find eclipse plugins without getting sick will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, you don't need a plugin, you just need to add the required libraries to your build path. You won't find those in update sites.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Locate and download the required JARs. You can use a service like [FindJar.com](http://findjar.com/) to search for those JARs. Apache JARs are usually available from apache.org.
2. Put the JARs in a folder called lib in your project.
3. Refresh the project in Eclipse (F5 or right-click and "Refresh"), the lib folder with the JARs should appear in your project explorer.
4. Add them to the build path - in the Eclipse project explorer, right-click the JARs and select "Add to build path"

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project ---> Properties ---> Java Build Path ---> Add Library... ---> Server Runtime ---> Apache Tomcat ----> Finish.